# Skype install - debian amd64. libdbus issues

Tags: debian, skype

I have looked quite thoroughly for an answer to this question to no avail. 
I am trying to install Skype on Debian amd64 (with Xfce, which shouldn't make any difference...).

After installing Skype the ''normal'' way

```
#dpkg --add-architecture i386
#apt-get update
#wget -O skype.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
#dpkg -i skype.deb
```

some dependencies cannot be satisfied, so I tried:

```
#apt-get install -f
```

to fix the broken packages. But this only seems to remove skype. So, something is seriously wrong.
In particular these dependencies:

```
libqt4-dbus:i386
libqt4-network:i386
libqtwebkit4:i386
```

are not met.

I am, however, unable to install any of them. I end up having to install `libdbus-1-3:i386`, but it will break `libdbus-1-3`, which in turn breaks `libdbus-1-3:i386`.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.6.8-1+deb7u1) but 1.6.8-1 is to be installed
    libdbus-1-3:i386 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.6.8-1) but 1.6.8-1+deb7u1 is to be installed
    skype:i386 : Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13) but it is not going to be installed
```

There is one word in German for this situation:
zwickenmuehle.

An ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just fetch the dynamic static package from skype.com? (Which works well)

Comment: @warl0ck when you say "dynamic static package" you mean the tar.gz package available for download? If so, 
yes, I have tried that, but the dependencies are still broken, and I still get stuck with same problem.

Comment: The common German word for this is "Zwickmühle" ( "Zwickenmühle" seems to be only used in street names, it is not in the common dictionaries. It could be that it is the name of a special mill and is not related to the [game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Men%27s_Morris) as Zwickmühle).

Comment: @Horacio yes, the tar.gz package

Comment: It is customary to note the Debian version. Is it stable/testing/unstable? I recently installed the skype 32 bit package on 64 bit wheezy/stable, and didn't encounter these issues. Note that the older 2.2.0.35-1 versions are on skypes server, but skype does not link to them. This is what I currently have installed - it may be an option for you.

Comment: I see that I downloaded from `wget -c http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb`. I think this works on debian stable without any changes. You need to download the corresponding i386 multiarch packages, and I also needed to install `libpulse0:i386` to get playback to work.

Comment: For the record, the reason why I ended up using 2.2 was because the microphone was not working for me. I haven't tried going back to 4.2, maybe that would work too.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you. I am, in fact, running stable. For some reason though, I cannot install the required dependencies. Some packages are still broken, even though multiarch is enabled. I created a small virtualbox VM with Debian 7 amd64 and on it, skype worked immediately. I will try for a few hours on the weekend and see what's what.

Comment: @Horacio: Maybe your system has some unofficial packages installed? Where does the `1.6.8-1+deb7u1` in `libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.6.8-1+deb7u1)` come from?

Answer (score 2):

This is common problem in 64 bits for installing Skype

First a downgrade is required and done with the following: create the 'preferences' file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=precise*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000.

Then you may downgrade the offending applications with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Then you may install packages that complained about dependencies, like
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch, or sudo apt-get install ia32-libs.
```

Finally, you should remove the file you just created:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences
```

Now download Skype From Official website(skype.com ) for multi architecture

then open the downloded package from software center then you should able to install skype

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully installed skype on my 64bit Linux Mint Debian (which is a Debian in all ways, not based on Ubuntu) by going to http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=debian32 to download the "multiarch" debian package (saved as `skype-debian_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb`) and installing it. The exact steps were *almost* the same as yours:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

After which I had a working `skype`. This is the "recommended" method according to
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12120/getting-started-with-skype-for-linux#2.2

Comment: Well, the only thing I find in [contrib](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=skype&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) are actually pidgin plugins for skype. And they require skype to work. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Horacio no you're not, I just don't know what I'm talking about apparently, my bad. I had `skype` working happily, uninstalled it so I can reinstall and show you the steps and now I can't install :). I'll update my answer as soon as I manage to get it to work.

Comment: @Horacio see updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much. But I have followed that exact same procedure you did, and the dependency problems arose anyway. And it was there where I got stuck.

Comment: could it be that I have Debian is not fetching the 32bit files it needs? My sources.list: 
`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib`

Comment: @Horacio So it is, I thought you were getting a different .deb but `diff` says otherwise. OK, well, I am using the LMDE repositories which are slightly different than debian's (but should be completely compatible, you could try them) and also, more likely, the debian.multimedia repos. Try adding something like `deb http://deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free`. Another possible difference is that I am tracking `testing` and not `stable` since this a relatively new `skype` it might well have dependencies from `testing` that are not in `stable`.